# Query eloquent in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

I have a problem with a query that I am doing in Laravel 5.8 using Eloquent, that I really don't know what happens.

I will explain:

My Eloquent query is this:

```
$naviones=DB::connection('naviones')->table('ps_customer')
            ->select('ps_orders.id_order','ps_customer.firstname','ps_customer.lastname','ps_customer.email','ps_address.address1',
                'ps_address.postcode','ps_address.city','ps_address.phone_mobile','ps_orders.id_order','ps_orders.reference',
                'ps_order_detail.product_name','ps_order_detail.product_quantity','ps_shop.name as tienda','ps_carrier.name as transportista')
            ->join('ps_address','ps_customer.id_customer','=','ps_address.id_customer')
            ->join('ps_orders', function($join){
                $join->on('ps_address.id_customer','=','ps_orders.id_customer')
                    ->where('ps_address.id_address','=','ps_orders.id_address_delivery');
            })
            ->join('ps_order_detail','ps_orders.id_order','=','ps_order_detail.id_order')
            ->join('ps_shop','ps_order_detail.id_shop','=','ps_shop.id_shop')
            ->join('ps_carrier','ps_orders.id_carrier','=','ps_carrier.id_carrier')
            ->where('ps_orders.id_order','=',11389)
            ->get();
```

As you can see, I am making this query to a database, which is not necessarily the one used by the application. That eloquent query translates to this:

```
SELECT
`ps_orders`.`id_order`, 
`ps_customer`.`firstname`,
`ps_customer`.`lastname`,
`ps_customer`.`email`,
`ps_address`.`address1`,
`ps_address`.`postcode`,
`ps_address`.`city`,
`ps_address`.`phone_mobile`,
`ps_orders`.`id_order`,
`ps_orders`.`reference`,
`ps_order_detail`.`product_name`,
`ps_order_detail`.`product_quantity`,
`ps_shop`.`name` AS `tienda`,
`ps_carrier`.`name` AS `transportista`
 FROM
`ps_customer`
 INNER JOIN `ps_address` ON `ps_customer`.`id_customer` = 
 `ps_address`.`id_customer`
 INNER JOIN `ps_orders` ON `ps_address`.`id_customer` = 
 `ps_orders`.`id_customer`
 AND `ps_address`.`id_address` = ps_orders.id_address_delivery
 INNER JOIN `ps_order_detail` ON `ps_orders`.`id_order` = 
`ps_order_detail`.`id_order`
 INNER JOIN `ps_shop` ON `ps_order_detail`.`id_shop` = 
`ps_shop`.`id_shop`
 INNER JOIN `ps_carrier` ON `ps_orders`.`id_carrier` = 
`ps_carrier`.`id_carrier`
 WHERE
`ps_orders`.`id_order` = 11389
```

Well, the point is that if I take that query and execute it in Mysql, it gives me the information that I am requiring, but, in eloquent the collection, it is empty. That is what drives me crazy that the collection is empty. That query is being delivered to me by eloquent, how am I ensuring that it is delivered by eloquent? I generated an error on purpose in one of the fields for Laravel to inform me and show me the complete query to examine it and that is the query:

[image]

At the end of the red circle I show the error created on purpose to see the complete query and see if it is well armed.

I do not understand what is happening, I do not know what to do, I have two days and I have no idea of ​​what is happening.

I hope you can give me some idea, thanks.

Comment: First you haven't use the eloquent. You have used the Query Builder.

Comment: How do you check if the collection is empty? (Not using Eloquent, that's the Query Builder)

Comment: What I would do is strip out all of the joins line by line - rather than trying to tackle it all at once, find out where the problem lies; at which line is this returning an empty collection? Then we can work from there.

Comment: Note: if you want to see/debug the query generated you can replace `->get()` with `->toSql()` and then `dd($naviones)`, no need to generate an error on purpose.

Comment: Yes you have right, is query builder, the collection is empy because,when i do dd($naviones) i can see the array is empty.

Comment: Hi party-ring  the problem is in the second join. I can see what is the problem, the problem is this seccion of the query: ->join('ps_orders', function($join){
                $join->on('ps_address.id_customer','=','ps_orders.id_customer')
                    ->where('ps_address.id_address','=','ps_orders.id_address_delivery');
            }) i need change this and for the any way push the inner manualy

Answer (score 1):

If you remove this:

```
->join('ps_orders', function($join){
            $join->on('ps_address.id_customer','=','ps_orders.id_customer')
                ->where('ps_address.id_address','=','ps_orders.id_address_delivery');
        })
```

is there any result? maybe the problim in this function.

also, can you change this:

```
DB::connection('naviones')->table('ps_customer')
```

to

```
DB::table('ps_customer')
```

Comment: I need especificate the connection because, the information is in other BD that is not the principal BD of the aplication.

Comment: the function do that exist this query: INNER JOIN ps_orders ON ps_address.id_customer = ps_orders.id_customer AND ps_address.id_address = ps_orders.id_address_delivery. I want say is, that this function add the conector AND, exist other way for add this conector to query?

Comment: can you remove **'='** from last line  ->where('ps_orders.id_order','=',11389)
, it could be the problem

Comment: also from this line ->where('ps_address.id_address','=','ps_orders.id_address_deli

Comment: i removed the '=' and the problem is the same

Comment: yeah! i removed all '=' and the problem is same.

Comment: Try to move the select after all joins

Comment: Hi everybody, how i will can representate for other way this query? ->join('ps_orders', function($join){
                $join->on('ps_address.id_customer','=','ps_orders.id_customer')
                    ->where('ps_address.id_address','=','ps_orders.id_address_delivery');
            })